# How to get Vaadin 8 grid column type?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I am using Vaadin 8 for Tabular data representation with dynamic bean. so i have to define logical filter on column.

For that i need column **datatype** from grid or column object.
Is there any way to get data types of column?

In Vaadin 7 i can get using **container.getType(columnName)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Vaadin 8 data binding model](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-overview.html), the property type is not explicitly known by the UI component (in your case `Grid`). This information should come from your domain model.

If difficult to retrieve from your domain model, you can do:

```
// instead of new Grid(beanType)
PropertySet<YourBeanType> ps = BeanPropertySet.get(beanType);
Grid g = new Grid(ps);
...
// get the property type
// okay, this is ugly, but you get the idea
Class<?> type = ps.getProperty(yourPropertyName).get().getType();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type of the column, when setting the `styleGenerator` for the column. For example, I do the following to set a specific style if the column is a `BigDecimal`:

```
Grid.Column c = grid.getColumn("id");
c.setStyleGenerator(obj -> {
       Object value = c.getValueProvider().apply(obj);
       if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
           return "align-right";
       } 
       return null;
 });
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to get it "outside" of the style generator.

Comment: In this case you get the type of the *instance*. Not always the same as the property type of the bean (although it is assignable from)

Comment: While clever and possibly useful, this is not a `getter` so much as a `guesser`.